# Test a substring with special character in a list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list with some application landscape names and I have to look for an specific application with special characters in Jinja2

> landscape_list: ["cmdb:app1 landscape", "cmdb:app2 (ex app3) landscape",
>   "cmdb:app4 landscape"]
>   app_to_look: "app2 (ex app3)"

I'm trying to use this code to test the list:

```
{{landscape_list | select('search',land_key) | list | count > 0}}
```

But I'm always getting 0 when I tried to test "app2 (ex app3)".
I think this problem is related with special characters like ().

Is it possible to look into a list for that specific application in jinja2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using a similar method. Instead of using *search*, I used *contains* as a search method

```
{{completed_list | select('contains',solution_search) | list | count > 0}}
```

solution_search contains the full name of what I'm looking.

```
{%-set solution_search = env_key ~' '~env_server_key ~' TEST'-%}
```

Where **env_key** is the application name that can contain special characters and **env_server_key** is the application environment.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"This problem is related to special characters like ()."*

A: Yes. The parenthesis must be escaped in the regex. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        land_key: 'app2 \(ex app3\)'
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ landscape_list|select('search', land_key)|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ landscape_list|select('search', land_key)|list|length }}"
    - debug:
        msg: One or more items match the searched pattern.
      when: landscape_list|select('search', land_key)|list|length > 0
```

give

```
    "msg": [
        "cmdb:app2 (ex app3) landscape"
    ]

    "msg": "1"

    "msg": "One or more items match the searched pattern."
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a list of keys to look for.

Comment: Why didn't you say so in your question? There is no list of keys.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was implicit. I'm sorry

Comment: No problem. I'm curious, what reasoning might lead to the conclusion it's implicit?

Comment: Well, in the code, {{landscape_list | select('search',land_key) | list | count > 0}}, I used land_key.
Normally, I use _key or _value to go over dictionaries. That is why I assumed it was it was implicit.